# Syntax Error, debugging help (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, token

I'm getting this error when I view my console, and this error is conflicting with another plugin I have on my page:

```
window.event("domready", function() {
     alert($("document").ready(function() {
        $(".flip").click(function() {
            $(".module").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });

  $(window).resize(function() {
 if($(window).width() > 800) {
  location.reload();
 }
}););
    });
```

I've tried re-writing it in case there was any extra spaces or anything. I don't really want to get rid of this script, because it's part of the responsiveness of my site.
Here is a link to my site: http://guitarworldcityarcade.com.au/index.php
Something in this script is disabling the drop-down functionality of my menus and I cannot find out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achive, but there're syntax errors in the code snippet you provided.
Here is the fixed version (But I still wonder why you have that `alert(...)`:

```
window.event("domready", function() {
    alert($("document").ready(function() {
        $(".flip").click(function() {
            $(".module").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    }));

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width() > 800) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

Now there is only 'TypeError: window.event is not a function' error, but I left it for you.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this :

```
window.event("domready", function()
{
    alert(
        $("document").ready(function()
            {
                $(".flip").click(function()
                    {
                        $(".module").slideToggle("slow");
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    );

    $(window).resize(function()
        {
            if($(window).width() > 800)
                {
                    location.reload();
                }
        }
    );

});
```

But what are you trying to do with your alert ? Seems weird...

Comment: it gives me 'SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'

Answer (score 0):

It seems you somehow have forgotten to remove `alert(` when debugging or something.

```
//This
alert($("document").ready(function() {

//should be
$("document").ready(function() {
```